# What is (the source of) this quote about God's turning any evil into good?

Tags: catholicism, good-and-evil

This is a quote-identification, except I don't actually know the quote. So bear with me, please. It's something like

> There is no sin so great that God could not turn it to good.

*or*

> The greatest trick God played on the devil was turning everything he did to good.

or something like that. (Though the second is obviously colored by *The Usual Suspects*.)

---

I suspect it's an aphorism from someone like Balthasar Gracian (not him, though) or Meister Eckhart, or it's a quote from Augustine or Francis (any--pick your favorite), or some famous teacher or commentator summarizing/paraphrasing one of the greats.

It could be related to or derived from either of Gn 50:20 or Romans 8:28, or not. It *isn't* either of those, though.

I tagged it Catholicism because I'm an American Catholic, and went to a Catholic college, and virtually all of my religious education has been from those sources. The ancient Greeks (not likely, though, for this one!), Church Fathers, monastics, Aquinas, &c. are likely suspects. C.S. Lewis, G.K. Chesterton, Thomas Merton....

I probably heard it at least fifteen years ago, so no need to consider 21st-century sources.

Does this ring a bell? **Is there a notable quote by a notable author/speaker/teacher in Christianity that fits this mold?**

Comment: Did you mean to say "no sin so great" or "no evil so great" that God can't turn it into good?

Comment: Could be either? (I mean, I know there's a theological distinction to be drawn between the two, I'm just saying I don't have a strong recollection of whether the quote was talking about one vs. the other.)

Comment: There is in deed a difference because sin is a sub set of evil, and evil is the larger category or "thing" in itself. I also suggest a ref to the genesis 50:20 passage since I have an idea that it informs the aphorism. Your call.  Then again, what kind of evil ?  for Aquinas, evil is "malus" which isn't as loaded a term as our current usage of that word.  It was more "absence of good than anything deeper than that."

Comment: Ahh, yes, thanks for reminding me about Gn (and, by extionsion, Rom). I don't really remember much more about the $bad_thing the quote references to narrow it down further, sorry.

Comment: For whatever reason, I am reminded of CS Lewis's "The greatest trick the devil ever pulled was convincing the world he doesn’t exist", but that's not what you asked about.

Comment: @bradimus right--if anything, it'd be a *riposte* to that.

Comment: Could it be related to the scripture,"Though your sins be as scarlet, they shall be white as snow."? (Isaiah 1: 18)

Comment: For some reason, I believe it to be in St Thomas Aquinas' writings.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not G.K. Chesterton, it's not his back catalogue of his popular witticisms at least. It might be the entire point of _The Man Who Was Thursday_ though.

Comment: @PeterTurner Yeah, good point.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are referring to this quote:

> In God’s hands intended evil becomes eventual good.

It was written by Max Lucado in his book *God Will Use This for Good: Surviving the Mess of Life*.  I'd say that he's a relatively famous Christian author, so perhaps this is the quote you're looking for.

Here's where I found this information:

https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/24515175-god-will-use-this-for-good-surviving-the-mess-of-life

http://www.faithgateway.com/what-was-meant-for-evil-god-uses-for-good/#.WYXZCIjyvIU

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for offering a helpful answer to this question. I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site as well.